# Symfony fpOpenIdBundle Steam return url not working

Tags: symfony, openid, steam

I've got a project with register and log in form/pages. I'm trying to use fpOpenIdBundle to validate someone's steam account and store its steamID to database. I followed the documentation, and I get redirected to steam, and when i sign in, I get redirected to the base url (none of my Controller actions are called).

I tried to understand whats happening in the bundle with little to no success.
Here's what I changed:

security.yml

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        fp_openid: 
            check_path: /login_check_openid
```

routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

fp_openid_security:
    resource: "@FpOpenIdBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
```

On my profile (/profile) page, where user should 'Sign in through steam', to validate his Steam account, I posted a form

```
<form id="fp_openid_login" action="{{ path("fp_openid_security_check") }}" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="openid_identifier" name="openid_identifier" value="" />
    <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

in which I pass the input value
    http://steamcommunity.com/openid

And when I sign in, 
[the following routes are called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brVLv.png)

Basically, steam calls endpoint /login_check_openid with GET request, and it redirects me to my localhost (.dev). I tried to record the sequence of actions that are called (with file_put_contents), but none of actions from SecurityController were called.
I want to know why do I get redirected and how come even though /login_check_openid endpoint exists, no actions were called for that endpoint?

Comment: I tried to use this bundle to make a steam authentication with the steam API, I worked a couple of day on it, but there is alway a new problem with this bundle... So a make a custom authenticator with [Guard](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/guard-authentication.html), it's easier and lighter than using this bundle. This method work perfectly (authentication + saving data in DB)